# Call Method Model in a Controller rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, model, controller

newTransaction doesnt save.

Method model:

```
def self.newTransaction(sesion,date) 
   t = Transaccion.new(sesion:'sesion',date:'date')                         
   newTransaction.save
end
```

Controller:

```
Transaccion.newTransaction("vianny.mo@gmail.com","12-12-12")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use `create` and save your self the extra line

```
def self.newTransaction(sesion, date) 
  create(sesion: sesion, date: date)                         
end
```

since the method (create) has no receiver, it will be sent to self, which I assume is the same class you want to create the method for

Answer (score 0):

Use `t.save` instead of `newTransaction.save`.